# How to add plotly-plot bar chart legend click event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, charts, plotly

Below code is for my plotly-plot charts in angular template, I want add color picker on clicking the chart legend. How can I get a click event for chart legends

```
 <plotly-plot
    [divId]="graph.selectedGraph.name"
    [data]="graph.selectedGraph.data"
    [config]="graph.selectedGraph.config"
    [layout]="layout"
    (relayout)="draggedShape($event)"
    [ngClass]="{ 'single-data': graph.data && graph.data.length === 1 }"
    #plotlyPlot
  >
  </plotly-plot>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `(legendClick)` event handler for the  [`plotly_legendclick`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#legend-click-events) events, the same way you use `(relayout)` for `plotly_relayout` events.

Comment: how can I create a small popup box for legends to select two options on click? one menu item for color picker and one for hide bar of barchart

Comment: There are probably many ways to create popups using angular (with which I'm not familiar), and the question might have already been addressed here on SO, if not then feel free to ask it. Note that you will need to return `false` in the (legendClick) handler to prevent the plotly_legendclick's default behavior, which toggles trace visibility.